# Change properties file without redeploying war

Tags: java, web-services, properties, war

Is it possible to change the .properties file without redeploying the war file?
I've made a RESTful web service with a properties file in the scr dir. This file contains the key-value pairs needed to make a database connection (url/driver/user/password).
But when I edit my .properties file, I need to redeploy the war to make these changes work.

Is there another way to do this, so the redeploy isn't necessary?

*P.S. My web service will be installed on other PC's. I want the users to only have to change to properties file to switch databases, not redeploying the war/restarting server.*

Comment: you can edit your file .properties and restart server.

Comment: Why not define the database connection as a datasource in your server? Because here's the thing: the database you connect to usually depends on the environment you deploy your application to. You will probably want a different database for your development environment and your production environment as an example, but perhaps you also want a separate test server with its own database.

Comment: @Gimby: That was the main reason to add a properties file. My web service will be installed on other PC's. I want the users to only have to change to properties file to switch databases, not redeploying the war.

Comment: Hence my suggestion for using a server datasource, which is basically designed to solve your exact requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Despite its a really short answer...*

Yes, you can change your ***.properties*** file and restart your ***server*** in order to update that properties that the server takes for its execution.

Comment: Thanks for the accurate answer. My next question would then be, how? ;)

Comment: @Camelaria You are welcome! If this is the right answer i ask you to mark as correct, in order to not keep unaswered questions. To edit the .properties, you could access to de .war as a zip file and make the changes you want, the save the changes.

Comment: @Camelaria  If the server is located on a remote pc, you can access using winscp or or putty and change the .properies file as any file. If the application is installed and a folder was created, change the .properties from the folder and not the war.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Another way would be to configure property files using JVM parameter. Eg. pc_${NAME}.properties